# How to see the training samples my neural network mised in python tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I just got started coding neural networks and my code si as follows

```
#create model
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(16, activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(16, activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")
])
model.compile(optimizer="adam",
              loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
              metrics=["accuracy"])

#train model
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
```

But how do I see what training samples my model got wrong. printing history gives me 
`<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History object at 0x000000001CCAB2B0>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `model.predict` to predict the labels on images. So for the training images you could do:

```
import numpy as np
y_probabilities = model.predict(x_train)
y_pred = np.array([np.argmax(probs) for probs in y_probs]
```

and then compare `y_pred` with `y_train`. For example

```
np.where(y_pred != y_train)[0]
```

will give you a numpy array with all the indices of the images that the model got wrong. Please refer to [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification) Keras tutorial for more details.